# Show a Toast message from inside uiThread Runnable?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, toast

I want to show a toast message from within a thread that is running on the UiThread however it appears the Runnable is not referenced correctly in my call. Please see my very basic implementation below:

```
this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Authenticated.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
);
```

I believe that **this** is not the actual runnable that the **makeText** function requires. How would you get the actual Runnable in this case?

Comment: `this` refers to activity context?.

Comment: better try yourclass.this

Comment: use `YourActivity_Name.this` instead of `this` because `this` refer to the run method context instead of Activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do not use `this` keyword,best practice is to create Context variable and initialize it in `onCreate` method,and use every where in your activity.

```
Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layoutname);
    context=this;
}
```

now use it like this:

```
this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Authenticated.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
);
```

in your case,this refers to the **runnable** class not the Context. so you can use `context` for `toast`

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(youractivityname.this, "Authenticated.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
);
```

`this` refers to the runnable class not the `context`. so you can use the `activityname.this`